# Widget instance options not showing correctly

Tags: plugin-development

i have a setup like

```
function form($instance) {
    $defaults = array(
        'title' => 'Recent Products',
        'number_products' => 3
    );
    $instance = wp_parse_args($instance, $defaults);
```

but my title is ok but number_products always does not show. i debuged in netbeans and found that form() is run 2 times and 1st time, variables look like

```
$instance = array(0)
// after wp_parse_args, 
$instance = array('title' => 'Recent Products', 'number_products' => 3);
```

on 2nd run of `wp_parse_args`, i dont know why it runs the 2nd time,

```
$instance = array('title' => 'Recent Products', 'number_products' => null);
// after wp_parse_args
$instance = array('title' => 'Recent Products', 'number_products' => null);
```

i dont really know whats happening ... can some1 enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found the answer, its actually not a problem with the code i posted. its in the `update()` function. i have some validation code

```
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    $instance['title'] = esc_attr(strip_tags($new_instance['title']));
    if (is_int($new_instance['number_products'])) {
        if ($new_instance['number_products'] > 0)
            $instance['number_products'] = $new_instance['number_products'];
        else
            $instance['number_products'] = 1;
    } else {
        $instance['number_products'] = $old_instance['number_product'];
    }

    return $instance;
}
```

the problem is at 2 places. i should be using [`is_numeric`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) over [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php), the reason is

> To test if a variable is a number or a
>   numeric string (such as form input,
>   which is always a string), you must
>   use is_numeric().

then, in the else, `$old_instance['number_product']` should have be plural `$old_instance['number_products']`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about two runs either. Had you tried just dumping content inside function instead of debug? Something like this:

```
function form( $instance ) {

    var_dump( $instance );

    $defaults = array(
        'title' => 'Recent Products',
        'number_products' => 3
    );
    $instance = wp_parse_args($instance, $defaults);

    var_dump( $instance );
```

Comment: yes. that way, i will get just what i specified "on 2nd run" where both $instance-es are `array('title' => 'Recent Products', 'number_products' => null);`

Comment: Then it's likely issue with what gets passed to function and not function itself. I am not too confident with widget form specifics will try to poke it later. Could you please update question with full code of your widget? Or at least enough that I can copy and test.

Comment: thanks rarst, its actually my mistake i have created an answer